# Error Message for Password in ASP.NET Identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I recently update my VS 2013 to Update 4, which came with a class file called `IdentityConfig.cs` under the `App_Start`. Inside the file, there is a part of the code which allows me to configure the password requirement:

```
manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 6,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
            RequireDigit = true,
            RequireLowercase = true,
            RequireUppercase = true,
        };
```

I change the length to `RequiredLength = 10` (for example), then I run the project by going into `Register` to try to create a new user, and here's the problem I'm encountering:

When I enter a password that is less than 6 characters, it will show an error message saying `"Passwords must be at least 6 characters"`;

And when I enter a password that is between 6-9 characters, it will show me an error message `Passwords must be at least 10 characters"`. Why is this happening, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Do you have some input validation on your password field in your model that sets the minimum length to 6 characters?

Comment: I created a new project using the template generated by VS 2013, I have not changed anything else besides that RequireLength

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it would help if you actually posted the REAL error message.  You just copied and pasted one of them and changed the number.  The real first error message would have been:

"The Password must be at least 6 characters long" and not "Passwords must be at least 6 characters"  This is the first clue that you're dealing with a different validation when the message is different.

If you look in AccountModels.cs you will see this in the RegisterViewModel:

```
[Required]
[StringLength(
   100, 
   ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.",
   MinimumLength = 6)]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "Password")]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

Notice that the minimum length is set to 6 for the stringlength.  Change that to 10.

Comment: You are right, the error messages are slightly different. Anyway, I guess the next question is, why are there 2 different validations?

Comment: @C.J. - one is an input validation, for client-side so it doesn't require a server round trip.  The other is a logical validation in the identity module itself (which has more complex validation).  Input validation is more simplistic.  If you are that concerned, you can remove the input validation but then you'll get a round-trip.

Comment: @C.J. -  get used to this, by the way.  You should always have both input validations and logical validations in your business layer and possibly even data layer validations.

Comment: I got `Passwords must be at least 6 characters` problem too, but I want create user in "seed" method. How can I do? I tried `new ApplicationUserManager` but no luck.